# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Direct update feature is not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

I have successfully created ipa for iOS7 using Worklight6. But its direct update feature is not working.
When it completes its update , iPhone just shows a white blank screen. 
Does anyone know its solution?

Thanks

Comment: Is this specific to iOS 7?

Comment: What is your Xcode version? What is your iPhone model?

Comment: This defect is specific to iOS7 only.. I am using XCode5 and used iPhone4S. It is also not working in simulator. As specified in one of the link, updated worklight also. But problem persists. Any idea?

Comment: Like to add one thing..... I am using IBM Worklight Developer Edition(installed from Eclipse Marketplace).

Comment: @user2832448, is it still not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following setup and Direct Update worked OK for me:

- Worklight 6.0.0.1 (latest, make sure you are up-to-date via `Help > Check for updates`; version number should be `6.0.0.20130926`)
- Xcode 5
- iPhone 4S running iOS 7.0.2
- iOS Simulator running iOS 7